# How to find checksum for bitcoin public address without publick key

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

Say that I have an incomplete public address like this one `11B6X2JLR3FB6GU7GHUoK7C6FXWL`
as you can see it's `28` characters only, missing the `6` characters checksum, however I do not have public key to generate address (and don't have the private key)

For a demonstration purpose of my project at university I want to find the checksum characters so I get an address that looks like `11B6X2JLR3FB6GU7GHUoK7C6FXWL[xxxxxx]` change `[xxxxxx]` to the checksum characters.

I have read the bitcoin wiki on how public addresses are generated from `private`/`public` keys, but I don't have those two. I know I won't be able to spend the coins sent to this address since I don't have it's `private` key (and doubt anyone have it, but it's for a university project. vanity gen isn't an option since I need to match all `28` characters which is mathematically impossible...

Preferable if it's possible to show the code to do it in Ruby, if you don't know Ruby then the steps will be find and I'll work the code my self.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script from the thread "Python code for validating bitcoin address" an https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1026.0 There are implementations in many different languages.

After that you can generate array of addresses (58**6 = 38,068,692,544 addresses)and feed it to the script and after some time you'll get array of valid public addresses.

Comment: So there is no mathematical way, rather I'll have to try brute force the address? Also is there a possibility that I won't find a valid address?

Comment: I don't know other way. May be someone have it.

Comment: Where from you get first part of address (28 chars)? If it from real address you find the valid address.

Comment: The first 28chars are generated randomly, however they always meet the address requirements of not including characters 'l' '0' 'I' 'O'.
Is there a limit on how many characters can be generated randomly and insuring an address will be found?